# Segmentation Fault 11 redux

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault, glut

I am writing a program that should create random sized green boxes at random locations in a 640x480 window. I am getting a segmentation fault when I run the following code. The problem resides in the two "for" loops. The segfault usually occurs in the nested "for" loop with startx. I suspect a buffer overflow, but don't know how to make less bulky code.

```
//Globals
int width, height;
int endx, endy, starty, startx, randEnd, randStartX, randStartY;
unsigned char *pixmap;

void setPixels(){

for (int j = 1; j<100; j++) { // j == j-1 # of boxes

    randStartX = rand() % width; // random # btw 0 and width
    randStartY = rand() % height; // random # btw 0 and height
    randEnd = 1 + (rand() % 100); // random # btw 0 - 100, not allowing box > 100.

    startx = randStartX;
    starty = randStartY;
    endx = startx + randEnd;
    endy = starty + randEnd;

    for(int y = starty; y < endy; y++) { // first y coordinate of box
        for(int x = startx; x < endx; x++) { // first x coordinate of box
            cout << "endx = " << endx << endl;
            int i = (y * width + x) * 3; // movement upwards for each pixel
            pixmap[i++] = 0x00; //Increments i by one to move to the next part of pixel.
            pixmap[i++] = 0xFF; 
            pixmap[i] = 0x00; 
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //initialize the global variables
    srand (time(0));
    width = 640;
    height = 480;
    pixmap = new unsigned char[width * height * 3];  

    setPixels(); // write code like ./pr01 red, etc.

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100); // Where the window will display on-screen.
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutCreateWindow("Assignment 01");
    init();
    glutReshapeFunc(windowResize);
    glutDisplayFunc(windowDisplay);
    glutMouseFunc(handleButton);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0; 
}
```

Any idea of what could be causing this? Are there any blatant logic issues here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `pixmap` and the code that initializes it?

Comment: What does "bulky code" have to do with buffer overflows? Just make sure you've allocated the proper amount of space in `pixmap`.

Comment: What is `width` and `height`? It looks like you can create a box with `starty == height-1` and `endy == starty + randEnd`, width `randEnd > 0` this would result in writing outside the buffer.

Comment: I suspect a buffer overflow - it's quite trivial to check for it, isn't it? it's just an index.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`). Learn how to use a debugger (`gdb`) and a memory leak detector (`valgrind`)

Comment: Hello welcome to SO. In the future ould please post the variables pixmap, height, width. What's happening here is that you are writing outside the boundaries of your pixmap buffer. You should start at 0 on both x and y there! Or you will write outside the buffer. Unless pixmap is a really big buffer? I'm sure some may help if you post us some more code. :)

Comment: I have added these variables to the code, sorry for the omission. Thanks for all of the super fast responses!

Comment: @Autex There we go, It's a buffer overflow :) You must start at 0,0 on both x and y as stated above.

Comment: I assume that pixmap is created (memory allocated for it) to at least the size of 640x480*3 bytes?

Comment: @Stígandr -Thanks! Starting at 0, however, would mean that I would always start drawing the box in the lower left corner of the window, is this correct?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Good question, when I declare it globally, I do not allocate that much memory for it, only until I initialise in main do I give it those values. If any of this sounds stupid, sorry I'm a noob at programming.

Comment: @MichaelPetch "I already have unsigned char *pixmap = new unsigned char[640*480*3];  in main. Is that what you mean?"

Comment: I have provided a new answer that constrains endx and endy with modulo arithmetic to make sure whatever is chosen for randEnd will be clipped at the boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to look at this problem is assume the `randStartX` was set to 639 and `randStartY` to 479. Now you say find a random number to determine size of box (max 100). If you start from bottom right corner you can't create any box beyond the array bounds. your `randEnd` code has to account for boxes that exceed the bounds when added to `randStartX` and `randStartY` . randEnd needs to be constrained or in your 2 for loops you need to make sure that you constrain writing beyond the edge of the display area (pixmap).

The best way is to constrain `endx` and `endy`. You can do this and fix your bug by replacing

```
endx = startx + randEnd;
endy = starty + randEnd;
```

with:

```
endx = min(startx + randEnd, width-1);
endy = min(starty + randEnd, height-1);
```

Use the `min` function to limit the box so it doesn't extend beyond the edge of `width` and `height` (subtract 1 since we are 0 based)

Comment: I am currently plugging this in. Let's see if I can get it to work like this...

Comment: It would have constrained things okay but it may have produced boxes in a way you didn't intend. I noticed the anomaly after I posted it. Since startx and starty could be bigger than endx and endy. I have amended the solution so that the start coordinates do not exceed the end coordinates and replaced modulo with the **min** function.

Comment: True. I also came up with this (Its not as pretty as yours tho)

if(startx + randEnd > 640 )
  endx = randEnd - ((startx + randEnd) - 640);
else
  endx = startx + randEnd;
if(starty + randEnd > 480)
  endy = randEnd - ((starty + randEnd) - 480);
else
  endy = starty + randEnd;

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, if startx/y can be in 0..width/height-1 range, and randEnd in 1..100 range, the endx/y can easily overflow (e.g. startx=width-30 and randEnd=80).

Comment: I'm afraid i don't quite understand the logic 0-1 range and 1-100? It sounds like you may be on to something, tho.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem, as stated in the comment. With the code below you will only fill innside your buffer.

```
for(int y =0; y < randStartY ; y++) { // first y coordinate of box
    for(int x = 0; x < randStartX; x++) { // first x coordinate of box
        //cout << "endx = " << endx << endl;
        int i = (y * width + x) * 3; // movement upwards for each pixel
        pixmap[i++] = 0x00; //Increments i by one to move to the next part of pixel.
        pixmap[i++] = 0xFF; 
        pixmap[i] = 0x00; 
        }
    }
}
```

Since you are just dealing with colors here I assume this is what you are after. If you would be to copy a texture, weould have to do it a bit differently, with some offsets and stuff :)

Well anyhows I hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: "This will start drawing (I believe) the colored pixels at 0,0, which I don't want. I'd like the beginning x,y values of the lower left corner of the boxes to be at random locations. Does that make sense?"

Comment: @Autex Okay, then I missunderstood you there. I see have you gotten your answer so I won't edit.

Comment: Thank you anyway! It did help me to understand the problem, however.